How do you interpret this question: "Have you shared anything with others recently?"
This is an IELTS speaking question and when I heard it, I instantly thought of sharing personal stories and feelings. However, all the model answers I've seen on the Net talk about sharing objects.
Did I interpret it the wrong way or are both ways acceptable and it was just a coincidence other people and I thought differently? In other words, when I'm in the exam room, what information do you think the examiner expects to hear from me? Object sharing or story/feeling sharing or either?

What is the purpose of the question? Is it to write an essay, an article, a story or are you asked to give a verbal answer? What may seem an unimportant detail to you, might be the key to understanding if the question is focused on materialistic things or more intimate and personal issues.

Sorry, I've just clarified it.

Is it part 1 or part 2 of the IELTS speaking? If it's part 1 your interpretation is legitimate, an examiner might be pleasantly surprised to hear a different approach.  However, could you speak for about two minutes about sharing your feelings with a friend or partner? Materialistic objects, such as an electric mower, shears, or a purse/handbag might be easier to talk about, you can include more details. You say why the person needed to borrow it, and why they came to you etc.

Oh yes it's for part 1. Thank you.

As you yourself realize, the word "share" is ambiguous there. It could refer to an object or to a personal story or an opinion. Your question seeks opinions on what the examiner meant. This site is not for advice on a particular test.

Not really. It's good if there's somebody who knows what the examiner means. But I never expect users here to know about it, hence the first question of whether I interpreted it differently from what native speakers normally do. That's something we as non-natives simply can't tell for sure.

You can see that at first, I didn't include any information about IELTS because I actually anticipated that people would say this site was not for IELTS. I only expanded on it when asked to.

A dictionary would tell you that the verb share has multiple meanings; what meaning it might have in a given sentence, one that gives no context, is a matter of opinion. No way to know if it's asking about a personal revelation or an object.

Meanings are clarified or created by contexts. We're given no context for this sentence. That's an artificial way of working, since we don't usually blurt single sentences to someone and walk away. If you are asked this question in person by an examiner, it should be ok to ask them to explain the meaning or provide context.
In the absence of a context, we often imagine one. When I read the title, I thought of other situations in which we're asked "Have you [done something] recently": official settings in which someone is filling out a form, like an airline security officer asking if you have received goods from a stranger, or a doctor asking if you have traveled outside the country. In this sort of setting, I would think of sharing physical objects (hypodermic needles, shared transportation), though I would still respond "Huh? What do you mean, shared what kind of thing?"
My immediate second thought was about a therapeutic setting, in which "share" would mean "speak openly to others." The word "share" is often used in group therapies to mean "have something to say to the other participants in the group," as in "You don't have to share if you're uncomfortable doing so. Greg, you shared last time; do you have anything new to share?"
So in other words, both of the meanings you thought of are valid and would be appropriate for different settings.
